# How to add key manager using REST API in WSO2 APIM 4.0

Tags: wso2, keycloak, wso2-api-manager

I want to use keycloak as keymanager with wso2 apim 4.0 . I did configure keycloak as key manager using manual steps mentioned in below doc.

[https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/administer/key-managers/configure-keycloak-connector/][1]

I successfully tested this integration of APIM and Keycloak. But now I want to automate this process. I am looking for a REST API of admin portal in APIM which will provide the functionality of adding keycloak as keymanager. I referred to the below link

[https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v2/admin-v2/#tag/Roles][1]

But I could not find any API here which will allow me to add keycloak as keymanager. Please help me to find this API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the key manager rest API - [https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v2/admin-v2/#tag/Key-Manager-(Collection)/paths/~1key-managers/post](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/reference/product-apis/admin-apis/admin-v2/admin-v2/#tag/Key-Manager-(Collection)/paths/%7E1key-managers/post)